# How do I change both the contents of a cell and its conditional formatting based on a cell in another column?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create a formula for column H using a date in column G.  If the value in the G cell is less than 0 then the H cell should have the value "Over" and turn red, or if the G cell is more than 0 then the H cell states "Under" and turns green.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely,

The formula for H is (write it in H1 and then copy for the whole column)

```
=IF(G1<0,"Over","Under")
```

Then go to menu Format > Conditional Formatting and set-up the formatting.

```
Apply to range: H:H
Format cells if... Text is exactly: Over
```

Add another rule

```
Apply to range: H:H
Format cells if... Text is exactly: Under
```

Formula **=IF(G1<0,"Over","Under")** means that if G is less than 0, then H will be Over. Otherwise (if G is more than 0 **or equal**), H will be Under. If you want to exclude 0, then you can use:

```
=IF(G1<0,"Over",IF(G1>0,"Under",""))
```